# Sorting Product Collections in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, special-price

I want to make a top offers block where special offer products with the highest percentage discount are shown.

I have my special offer products showing and just wondering if something like below is possible to sort these by their discount percentage:

```
$_productCollection->addFinalPrice()
          ->addMinimalPrice()
          ->getSelect()
          ->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price')
          ->limit(2);
          ->order('(price_index.price - price_index.final_price) / price_index.price' , 'DESC')
```

Failing that i would like latest offers (sorting by special from date descending) which i think should be like so:

```
$_productCollection->addFinalPrice()
          ->addMinimalPrice()
          ->getSelect()
          ->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price')
          ->limit(2);
          ->order('special_from_date' , 'DESC')
```

However this is not working. Has anyone any suggestions for how to use sort properly within Magento 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code

```
$_productCollection->addFinalPrice()
          ->addMinimalPrice()
          ->getSelect()
          ->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price')
          ->limit(2);
          ->order('special_from_date' , 'DESC')
```

to

```
$_productCollection->addFinalPrice()
              ->addMinimalPrice()
              ->getSelect()
              ->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price')
              ->limit(2);
              ->order('special_from_date DESC')
```

Comment: From what i can tell the below also works: ->order('((price_index.price - price_index.final_price) / price_index.price) DESC'); Thanks for your help! Not seen it like this on here however everything works now as expected.

Comment: @harri can you please put your entire code here thanks in advance

Comment: @HarshJayswal create a thread and tag me. I will share the code. this is a different scenario.

Comment: @Bojjaiah I am new here can you please tell me how to create a thread or i have posted a question on magento community following is link to my question there i have shared my code https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268575/display-product-with-highest-discount-on-top-using-sorting-in-magento-2