# Display On Sale Product On Top Sorting Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, magento2.3, toolbar

I have added a custom sorting option in default sorting menu by overriding toolbar.php file

1. I want to display  products with **the highest discount on top using sorting and product with no discount should also be displayed  after all discounted product**

Following is my Toolbar.php  file

```
<?php 
 namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Product\ProductList;
class Toolbar
{


/**
 * Plugin
 *
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject
 * @param \Closure $proceed
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
 */


public function aroundSetCollection(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $collection
) {
    // die(print_r($subject));
    $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
    $result = $proceed($collection);
    if ($currentOrder) {
        // if ($currentOrder == 'price_desc') {
        //     $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'desc');
        // } elseif ($currentOrder == 'price_asc') {
        //     $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'asc');
        // }
        if ($currentOrder == 'created_at_new') {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
        }
        elseif ($currentOrder == 'created_at_old') {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('created_at', 'asc');
        }
        elseif ($currentOrder == 'bestseller') {
            $subject->getCollection()->getSelect()->joinLeft( 
            'sales_order_item', 
            'e.entity_id = sales_order_item.product_id', 
            array('qty_ordered'=>'SUM(sales_order_item.qty_ordered)')) 
            ->group('e.entity_id') 
            ->order('qty_ordered desc');
        }
        elseif ($currentOrder == 'onsale') {



        }
    }

    return $result;
}
}
```

Following Image Is Output of Sorting Menu

[image]

Comment: is this code updated?

Answer (score 1):

try below code.

```
public function aroundSetCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject, \Closure $proceed, $collection)
{
    $returnValue = $proceed($collection);
    if ($subject->getCurrentOrder() == 'onsale') {
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setOrder('price', 'ASC');
        $collection->load();
    }
    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: Its not showing result as expected it shows non sale product also on top i want to show non sale products after all on sale products are  listed and thanks for your answer

Comment: @HarshJayswal Then create one **attribute** and assign to `attribute set`. if sale product set **yes** other than set **no**. Now `setOrder('attribute_name', 'ASC');`. It will work.

Comment: @HarshJayswal If add attribute add one more line `->joinField('attribute_name=1')` before `$collection->load();`.

Comment: it still shows incorrect result it might possible that i am not making it properly can you please update the answer